# How to write unicode in CSV using Python2

Tags: python, csv, unicode

I have a below python code which writes data into csv file.

```
            from StringIO import StringIO
            import unicodecsv as csv

            res_io = StringIO()

            csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(
                res_io, encoding='utf-8', fieldnames=header,
                delimiter=str(','), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC
            )
            # PyCharm Debugger
            # results: <type 'list'>: [{'review': {u'a': u'foo', u'b': u'bar'}, 'id': '1'}]
            csv_writer.writerows(results)
```

Output I get in CSV, `u` is prepend with key and value and I don't need that in output CSV.

[image]

Expected output in CSV(I have manually edited above output):

[image]

Comment: The easiest solution: use Python 3 instead. In any case, why do you expect the output to be that? It is `repr` of Python 2 dictionary, that is how it works with Unicode strings. One option would be to rewrite the entire dictionaries to use Python 2 strings etc.

Comment: I do not undestand the question here , you want the 'u' not to appear in the output csv ? The question seems to indicate something else.

Comment: It works in Python3 but I'm asking help for Python2.7.

Comment: Yes, I do not want `u` in output csv

Comment: Why are you writing dictionaries into CSV columns in the first place? At the very least then use a standard format, like JSON. Or not use CSV at all.

Comment: why would you even want *unsorted* dictionaries there? Perhaps you'd want to always write JSON with sorted keys instead?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you'd want to use JSON instead for consistent output

```
>>> json.dumps({u'a': u'foo', u'b': u'bar'}, sort_keys=True)
'{"a": "foo", "b": "bar"}'
```

As a bonus, with `sort_keys=True` the keys will be in alphabetical order.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import unicodecsv as csv
import json

res_io = StringIO()

csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(
    res_io, encoding='utf-8', fieldnames=header,
    delimiter=str(','), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC
)
# PyCharm Debugger
# results: <type 'list'>: [{'review': {u'a': u'foo', u'b': u'bar'}, 'id': '1'}]
csv_writer.writerows({'id': i['id'],
                      'review': json.dumps(i['review'], sort_keys=True)}
                     for i in results)
```

Comment: result is not constant, it may any number of key/value pair, for the simplify my question I gave example of 'id' & 'review' keys but in reality it can be any number of key/value pair stored by user.

Comment: @n33rma so adapt from what I've given to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import csv

res_io = StringIO()
header= ["review","id"]
csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(
    res_io,  fieldnames=header
    #delimiter=str(',')#, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC
)
csv_writer.writerows([ {k:str(i[k]).replace("u'","'")}if type(i[k])==dict else {k:i[k]} for i in results for k in i ])
```